# pgfplots output shifted figures when plotting customized function

Tags: pgfplots

I'm plotting a function using pgfplot. But the output is has some extra white space on the left of the figure. It's really strange. Can someone shed some light on it?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lap}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(2*#1)*exp(-abs(x)/#1)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,
    domain=-3:3,samples=50,smooth },
enlargelimits=upper
] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
\addplot{lap(1/0.5)};
\addplot{lap(1/0.75)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding a `%` symbol after the `\pgfmathparse{... }` expression

Comment: @Jake Wow, it works. So subtle. Could you explain why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.